# Parameterized substitutions (${foo%bar}, ${foo-bar}, etc) without using eval

Tags: bash, shell, environment-variables, eval

From `envsubst` man:

> These substitutions are a subset of the substitutions that a shell
>   performs on unquoted and double-quoted strings. Other kinds of
>   substitutions done by a shell, such as *${variable-default}* or
>   *$(command-list)* or *`command-list`*, are not performed by the `envsubst`
>   program, due to security reasons.

I'd like to perform variable substitution a string, supporting constructs like `${variable-default}` or `${variable%suffix}`. I don't want to allow running commands.

Apparently it's not possible using `envsubst`, on the other hand `eval` has serious security implications.

Is there some other possibility than writing custom interpolation function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` 4.4 introduced a new type of parameter expansion which might do what you want. Namely, `${foo@P}` expands the value of `foo` as if it were a prompt string, and a prompt string does undergo a round of expansion just prior to being displayed.

```
${parameter@operator}
    Parameter transformation.  The expansion is either a transforma-
    tion  of  the  value of parameter or information about parameter
    itself, depending on the value of operator.  Each operator is  a
    single letter:

    Q      The  expansion is a string that is the value of parameter
           quoted in a format that can be reused as input.
    E      The expansion is a string that is the value of  parameter
           with  backslash  escape  sequences  expanded  as with the
           $'...' quoting mechansim.
    P      The expansion is a string that is the result of expanding
           the value of parameter as if it were a prompt string (see
           PROMPTING below).
    A      The expansion is a string in the form  of  an  assignment
           statement  or  declare  command  that, if evaluated, will
           recreate parameter with its attributes and value.
    a      The expansion is a string consisting of flag values  rep-
           resenting parameter's attributes.
```

A quick example:

```
$ foo='${bar:-9}'
$ echo "$foo"
${bar:-9}
$ echo "${foo@P}"
9
$ bar=3
echo "${foo@P}"
3
```

It does, however, still allow running arbitrary commands via `$(...)`:

```
$ foo='$(echo hi)'
$ echo "${foo@P}"
hi
```

Another caveat: it does, of course, also expand prompt escapes, so you may be more expansions than you expected if your string already contains some backslashes. There is some conflict between prompt escapes and escapes intended for `echo -e`.

Comment: I am less of a fan of the `${foo@P}` than I was before. I can't tell if expansion of command substitution is a bug or a necessary evil.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report; at the very least, the man page should be explicit about the possibility of code execution.

Comment: Prompt strings have always expanded command substitutions; it's not clear that you could force expansion of a prompt outside of a "real" interactive shell (running a command with `bash -i` is not sufficient), but it does seem to be more of an issue with the new parameter expansion operator.

Comment: @chepner can you please share a link to the bug you've filled?